# Check and uncheck a button in a form created by Adobe acrobat

Tags: html, triggers

I have 5 different answers to one question which are not excluding. One can check the answer on a radio button. The form is created by Adobe Acrobat. I want to have the possibility to trigger every button, I mean if someone has checked by mistake a button to can by the next click with the mouse to uncheck the same button.

Comment: Any chance you can share what you've tried so far?

Comment: I can't see the code which is made by the Acrobat to change it.

Comment: I have tried to make a button which is checked and unchecked the next moment

Comment: I mean 5 radio buttons should determine the soil conditions: rock, rubble, sand, clay, loess. They has names, tooltip, style(check) and export value. If I give them the same name you can check only one button at a time. When I give them different names I can check but I can't uncheck every button.

Comment: It sounds like your use case is more appropriate to a native check box instead of trying to use radiobuttons as checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you! It works with checkboxes :)